# Introduce JSON in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I´m trying to introduce a JSON file in a mySQL database with Php and I´m not able to perform it.
    This is my  json file

```
{
    "recordcount": "2",
    "hoststatus": [
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "18683"
            },
            "instance_id": "1",
            "host_id": "101",
            "name": "www.chaoticmoon.com",
            "display_name": "www.chaoticmoon.com",
            "address": "www.chaoticmoon.com",
            "alias": {},
            "status_update_time": "2020-05-06 04:40:04",
            "status_text": "check_http: Invalid hostname/address - www.chaoticmoon.com",
            "status_text_long": {},
            "current_state": "1",
            "icon_image": "www_server.png",
            "icon_image_alt": {},
            "performance_data": {},
            "should_be_scheduled": "1",
            "check_type": "0",
            "last_state_change": "2019-06-06 12:24:40",
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "18682"
            },
            "instance_id": "1",
            "host_id": "188",
            "name": "www.acme.com",
            "display_name": "www.acme.com",
            "address": "216.27.178.28",
            "alias": {},
            "status_update_time": "2020-05-06 04:37:07",
            "status_text": "CRITICAL - 216.27.178.28: rta nan, lost 100%",
            "status_text_long": {},
            "current_state": "1",
            "icon_image": "server.png",
            "icon_image_alt": {},
            "performance_data": "rta=0.000ms;3000.000;5000.000;0; pl=100%;80;100;; rtmax=0.000ms;;;; rtmin=0.000ms;;;;",
            "should_be_scheduled": "1",
            "check_type": "0",
            "last_state_change": "2018-07-02 11:38:36",

        }
    ]
}
```

My code is the next, however I get some failures, how can fix them?

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$HostStatus = file_get_contents('../hostNAGIOS.json');
$contenido = json_decode($HostStatus,true);

$delete = "DELETE FROM nagioshost";
$ope = mysqli_query($conectar,$delete);

foreach($contenido as $row){
    $hostID = $row['hoststatus']['host_id'];
    $hostName = $row['hoststatus']['name'];
    $state = $row['hoststatus']['current_state'];
    $time = $row['hoststatus']['last_state_change'];

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO nagioshost(id,host_name,status,last_state_change) VALUES('$hostID', '$hostName', '$state', '$time')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conectar,$insertar);   

    if ($query) {
      echo "DATOS METIDOS";
    } else {
      echo "ERROR";
    }
}


mysqli_close($conectar);
?>
```

This is the result:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'hoststatus' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 18

Warning: Illegal string offset 'host_id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 18

Warning: Illegal string offset 'hoststatus' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 19

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 19

Warning: Illegal string offset 'hoststatus' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 20

Warning: Illegal string offset 'current_state' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 20

Warning: Illegal string offset 'hoststatus' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 21

Warning: Illegal string offset 'last_state_change' in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 21
DATOS METIDOS
Notice: Undefined index: hoststatus in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: hoststatus in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: hoststatus in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: hoststatus in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoTFG\BBDD\jsonConNAGIOS.php on line 21
DATOS METIDOS
```

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, so you'd look at it). Making your post clear, and showing that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers. (@ADyson fixed it for you.)

Comment: Hints: 1) the outer part of your JSON is an object, so doing a `foreach` through it doesn't make much sense (unless you wanted to list all the properties - but it's clear from the lines following it that you don't, you are trying to look at a specific property). 2) `hoststatus` is an **array**. So it doesn't have named properties. You need to access an index within the array first, and then a property of the object inside that. Example: `$contenido['hoststatus'][0]['host_id']` . Of course if you want to get all the host IDs from every row, you'd need to loop over `$contenido['hoststatus']`

Comment: [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) sez your json is invalid, so i guess your json_decode did not work ?

Comment: There is an extra comma after each `"last_state_change": "2019-06-06 12:24:40",`.  Those are properties, so it makes the object invalid.  Remove those extraneous commas and you will have valid json.